# codelldb in Neovim produces an error when connecting

Tags: c++, debugging, lldb, neovim, codelldb

So, I have the "codelldb" plugin installed using mason. However, once I try starting the debug session, it exits with return code 1, stating that the error was ECONNREFUSED. It is trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 with ${port}. I did try explicitly specifying the port, not sure if that changes anything, but the error remains. After unsuccessfully searching the web for other possible debuggers, as well as a solution to this problem, I am clueless.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, turns out I was following a tutorial for Mac.

Make sure the path to your LLDB has the correct extension in your nvim lua config. (**.so**)

```
local liblldb_path = extension_path .. "lldb/lib/liblldb.so"
```

Comment: Oh, I see. What should I pass the variable to though? `nvim-dap` should have all the options from `https://github.com/vadimcn/codelldb/blob/master/MANUAL.md`, however which one do I choose?